# W3 xHTML Validation Errors on jQuery code!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, w3c-validation

I have some jQuery code that, without it in the document it passes validation fine, but with it in it causes errors.  The code in question is here:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

            //Update error info
            errors = $(xml).find("Errors").find("*").filter(function ()
            {
                return $(this).children().length === 0;
            });

            if (errors.length == 0)
            {
                statuscontent = "<img src='/web/resources/graphics/accept.png' alt='' /> System OK";
            }
            else
            {
                statuscontent = "<img src='/web/resources/graphics/exclamation.png' alt='' /> "+errors.length+" System error"+(errors.length>1?"s":"");
            }

            $("#top-bar-systemstatus a").html(statuscontent);

            //Update timestamp
            $("#top-bar-timestamp").html($(xml).find("Timestamp").text());

            //Update storename
            $("#top-bar-storename").html("Store: "+$(xml).find("StoreName").text());
        }
    });
```

There are loads of other jQuery code on the page which all works fine and causes no errors so I cannot quite understand what is wrong with this.  The page isn't "live" so cannot provide a link to it unfortunately.

The error it lists is

> document type does not allow element "img" here

And the line of code it points to is here:

```
 statuscontent = "<img src='/web/resources/graphics/accept.png' alt='' /> System OK";
```

It also has an issue with the next assignment to `statuscontent`

Comment: Make your JavaScript code external.

Comment: @Gumbo agree, unless your hoster is punishing you with request limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are using XHTML. This is invalid indeed as the validator acts as if the code between the script tags is XML (XHTML is a subset of XML). This is invalid XHTML, as `img`-tags don't belong inside of `script`-tags.

To make it validate, use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) to escape any XML within your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

... your code
// ]]>
</script>
```

---

In HTML 5 this is not an issue. If you make a new website I'd recommend HTML 5 over XHTML. Use XHTML only if you are modifying an existing website.

Comment: If I do this Firebug reports a syntax error on the `<![CDATA[` line.  Also this website has to be compatible with older browser versions so unfortunately cannot depend on HTML5

Answer (score 1):

See [Script and Style Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) in The Differences From HTML 5.

Next see [the comparable section in the XHTML Media Types document](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4) since you are almost certainly serving your XHTML as HTML for IE compatibility.

(Then you'll probably do what I did back in '99 which is to throw you hands up in the air, scream "What's the point of using XHTML if I have to pretend it is HTML?!" and run back to HTML 4.01. (Or possibly onto HTML 5))

Comment: That sorted the W3 errors out, thanks, for some reason in IE though I get script errors.  No errors in W3 validation OR in Firebug console either.